# How to use Indirect and substitute formula for dropdown list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have created 2 dropdown menu one for the **operating client** and another for the **operating site** which filters down the dropdown list which are only applicable to "BlackPearl Resources Inc." (as shown below).

[image]

The 2 dropdown menu only works when the operating client name is one word and to get around it the only way is to insert underscores between each word which seems to be an restriction on the Namebox field. Without the underscore the **Operation site** dropdown menu doesn't work.

The picture below shows how they are linked in a separate worksheet with the leftmost column being the **Client's list** and subsequent right hand columns being **operating site**. I used the "Name from selection" method under formulas to group the dependable lists into the dropdown menu. Here is a link to the tutorial I used as reference: [Creating a Dependable dropdown list](https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/)

[image]

So to get around this how would you implement the Indirect and substitute function?

Comment: You posted a very identical question a few days ago and someone already provided you the solution in the comment. How about go back to your previous post and ask that user to demonstrate or provide you the link to the original answer of how to do the trick? If no luck let me know and I can show you how to do it.

Comment: @TerryW I did ask him no reply that why I made this in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Operating_Client**: all your client names;
- **BlackPearl_Resources_Inc.**: all operating sites under this client;
- **SonocoPhillips_Canada_Resources_Corp.**: all operating sites under this client.

A quick way of adding named ranges is to select the ranges you want to name including the header of the row/column and then press **Ctrl+Shift+F3**.

Once you have all the named ranges ready, go to **Data Validation** to set up the drop down list as shown below.

The formula for the Source of the **Operating Site** is:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(Operating_Client," ","_"))
```

You can choose to replace `Operating_Client` in the above formula with the actual cell where you have put the drop down list for **Operating Client** but putting in a name is better than putting in a cell reference.

[image: Example]

Cheers :)